# Liquibase- Using a customChange to update multiple tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, migration, liquibase

I am writing a migration that adds a column to all the tables that end with a specific suffix but I am having some trouble with it. My doubt is , how can I access the tables name from the database object?. I will leave my class and some pseudo code as commentary so I can contextualize the situation better

### Custom Task

```
public class AddColumnsCustomTask implements CustomTaskChange, CustomTaskRollback {
    private String suffix;
    private String columnName;
    private String columnType;

    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration","FieldCanBeLocal"})
    private ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor;

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public String getColumnType() {
        return columnType;
    }

    public void setColumnType(String columnType) {
        this.columnType = columnType;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
       /* for each table in database {
            if (table.name ends in this.suffix){
                table.addColumn(this.columnName)
            }
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationMessage() {
        return "Changes made";
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws SetupException {
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFileOpener(ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) {
        this.resourceAccessor=resourceAccessor;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationErrors validate(Database database) {
        return new ValidationErrors();
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback(Database database) throws CustomChangeException, RollbackImpossibleException {

    }
}
```

Comment: I see the liquibase tag, how is this liquibase related?

Comment: Because this class is used in Liquibase customChange tag